# how can i write the sql query to get the result set, get the result set from the max time

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Name       Longititue   latutute        Time
tharindu    79.94148    6.9748404       00:15:47
shane      79.8630765   6.8910388       13:23:24
shane      79.862815    6.8909349       14:41:29
shane      79.8628665   6.8911084       09:39:33
shane      79.8626956   6.890992        11:00:07
shane      79.8628831   6.89099         11:43:00
```

**i want get the result set as below**

```
shane      79.862815    6.8909349       14:41:29
tharindu    79.94148    6.9748404       00:15:47
```

how can i write the sql query to get the result set, get the result set from the max time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT Name,Longititue,latutute,[Time]
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Time] DESC) rn
    FROM T
)t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try using correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
where Time in (select max(Time) from tablename b where a.name=b.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use corelated subquery

```
select t.* from table_name t
 where t.[Time]=( select max([Time]) from table_name t1 where t1.Name=t.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use `ROW_NUMBER` without a formal subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    Name,
    Longititue,
    latutute,
    Time
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Time] DESC);
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this use CTE(Common Table Expression) and Ranking Function.

**SQL Query:**

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Name,Longititue,latutute,Time,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY time desc) as RN
    FROM MaxTime
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```